# Java Application - Load web page and check user selections in DOM

Tags: java, dom, frameworks

I want to build a Java application through which a user can request a web page, which loads in inside the Java application (not in a browser).
After the page loads, the user can select whichever elements they like on the page, and I want to track which elements they click through the DOM.

I.E. the user clicks the image of a product, then I want to get that particular element of the DOM, with all the attributes such as src, class, id, etc.

I'd like to know if any frameworks get close to doing anything like this. Especially the clicked elements, since the web page I am pretty sure there are quite a few ways to load in inside a Java application.

Comment: So you want to write your own browser in Java?

Comment: I would take a look at this https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-create-my-own-web-browser-with-Java as for tracking I'm not sure but as you would be loading the page I'm sure it's very possible.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I don't really know if it classifies as a browser, it's more for selecting elements on a webpage.

Comment: If your application should provide the user the ability to navigate on the web page through link clicks, it sounds a lot like a browser. Could you just use a real browser with a profiler plugin?

Comment: @MickMnemonic Do you think it would be easier to create a Chrome Extension for example, and use that to detect what my user clicks and selects, and give him options about the clicked elements through the extension?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you have in mind, but you can try to take a look at HtmlUnit http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html . It is said that it is used for unit tests, but it can be used also for other purposes; one of the descriptions I found is:

"A java GUI-Less browser, which allows high-level manipulation of web pages, such as filling forms and clicking links; just getPage(url), find a hyperlink, click() and you have all the HTML, JavaScript, and Ajax are automatically processed."